# Youtube unique views data available via API?

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I'm aware the "uniques" metric has been deprecated in the Youtube analytics API.  However, the new youtube studio beta shows some sort of derived "unique viewers" metric, as per https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7577916?hl=en
Indeed, I can see this metric by clicking on "Analytics", then "Reach Viewers" via the Youtube Studio Beta web interface.

It seems there should be a way to grab this metric via the Youtube analytics API, and yet I can find no documentation on how to do this.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I have this same question - have you learned anything about it?

Comment: I have the same requirement. Have you got anything?

Comment: [@Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9008653/jacob) [@DebiprasadMishra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4324123/debiprasad-mishra) [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71987890) on another identical StackOverflow question solves this problem.