# With the YouTube API, how can I get the Unique viewer for a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

It's confusing some doc says it's deprecated but other pages explains how to see it in the web interface. If it's visible from studio.youtube.com it should be accessible from the API... right?

**Q: With the API, how can I get the Unique viewer for a YouTube video?**

---

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics#uniques): The uniques metric was deprecated on September 27, 2016. It is not a core metric and will be supported until October 31, 2016.

But it is still present in the Studio Interface as described in the [page of the Help Center](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7577916?hl=en)

[image]

Comment: Does an answer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71490683/7123660) (in term of kind of answer) interest you ? If so I can add this feature to my open-source [YouTube operational API](https://yt.lemnoslife.com).

Comment: I would prefer an official way instead of a "screen scrapper" but it's a nice idea.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was looking for a solution as above but it took a lot of time due to YouTube time limitation in terms of *data processing* for my tests. So after having found a new method [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970181/7123660), I realized that it would be an alternative solution that I found easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go on your [Video analytics interface](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-build_audience/period-default) in YouTube Studio.

Open the `Web Developer Tools` `Network` tab of your web-browser (by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> on Firefox for instance).

Now select `Audience`, pay attention to select one of following:

- [First 24 hours](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-build_audience/period-since_publish,time_period_unit_nth_days,1)
- [Last 7 days](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-build_audience/period-week)
- [Last 28 days](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-build_audience/period-4_weeks)
- [Last 90 days](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-build_audience/period-quarter)

Because options:

- [Since published](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-build_audience/period-since_publish)
- [Last 365 days](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-build_audience/period-year)
- [Since uploaded (lifetime)](https://studio.youtube.com/video/VIDEO_ID/analytics/tab-build_audience/period-lifetime)
- Others depending on the time of video upload

Are maybe unavailable (depends on the time of video upload):

> Total number of unique viewers is only available for periods of up to
> 90 days to ensure data quality.

You should see a request to `get_cards`, copy it as cURL (by right-clicking).

Pay attention to remove `-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br'` from it in order to get the JSON response in a human readable format. Otherwise you would face the following warning:

> Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output " to save to a file.

In `--data-raw` request argument `--data-raw '{"screenConfig":{"entity":{"videoId":"VIDEO_ID"}` pay attention to change the `VIDEO_ID` for the one interesting you.

Execute the modified cURL request and your `Unique viewers` value is in the JSON response at the key `/cards/7/keyMetricCardData/keyMetricTabs/3/primaryContent/total`.

Comment: Wow!  That's nice. Still hacky... but with the proper Cookie it works!

I would have prefer a legit way, but I guess that's about it... thanks

Comment: Glad to have helped 

Comment: Seems this is not working workinymore. I cannot find a `get_screen`request. A yes weeks ago I was able to do this.

Comment: @eDeviser [I modified accordingly my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71987890/revisions), let me know if it's still not working on your end.

Comment: @eDeviser I was able to make it work, but the request did not contain "get_screen" but rather started with "join?alt..." and the network request was displayed the second I applied the filters I was interested in Youtube studio. (Thanks Benjamin for the tricky solution)