# Im getting a Quota exceeded response from the YouTube API but my quota limits are not reached yet

Tags: youtube-data-api

At least I think thats what this error message means:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 429 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet%2Cstatus&alt=json returned "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).". Details: "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).">
```

But my YouTube Data API v3 quotas have not been fully used up:
[image]
I have used 31k from my 112k limit and as I understand it the Queries per minute quota is higher than my daily limit, so that should also be no problem.

Am I understanding it right that this error happened because of Quota Limits or is this from another source?

My request basically was creating a new playlist.

Comment: As the [Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) endpoint costs a single quota per request, I guess that the limiting thing in your situation is about creating a new playlist. I recommend you to use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970181/7123660) to instantly create a new playlist in a quota-free manner.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I just dont see how the Quota is a problem since Im well below my limit and the Trick you mention is not really something I can do because it requires quite a bit of manual work. My use case should be completly automatic, just started by the user.