# Adding multiple videos to youtube-playlist in single api request (Python)

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

So I have this script that extracts users liked videos and creates a public playlist containing all liked videos but since there's quota limits I can't add more than 200 videos per day (playlistItems().insert() costs 50 quota /10,000).

Is there any way I can add videos in batches of 50 or something to avoid running out of quota ?

my current code:

```
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    "youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)

#code for fetching video id's in a list...

video_ids= [id1,id2,id3,id4,...]
playlist_id= "<playlist id>"

for id in video_ids:
    youtube.playlistItems().insert(
        part="snippet",
        body={
            "snippet": {
                "playlistId": playlist_id,
                "resourceId": {
                    "kind": "youtube#video",
                    "videoId": id
                }
            }
        }
    ).execute()
```

I've heard there's  `batch = youtube.new_batch_http_request()` but this doesn't seem to work for me, adds only 1 video and I think this still costs same amount of quota as above code.

Edit : Found Another way for Above thanks to benjamin but now stuck with this function only returning 991 video id's but liked playlist have 1900 videos.

```
def get_song_ids(youtube:object):
    
    video_ids,songs_names,songs_ids = [],[],[]
    next_page_token = None

    while True:
        try:
            # Getting the IDs of the user's liked videos.
            liked_videos_response = youtube.videos().list(
                part="id,snippet,contentDetails,status",
                myRating="like",
                maxResults=50,
                pageToken=next_page_token
            ).execute()
            #filtering song id's and extracting other info
            for item in liked_videos_response["items"]:
                video_ids.append(item["id"])
                title = item["snippet"]["title"]
                category_id = item["snippet"].get("categoryId")
                if category_id == "10":
                    songs_names.append(title)
                    songs_ids.append(item["id"])

            # Checking if there's more videos in playlist
            next_page_token = liked_videos_response.get("nextPageToken")
            
            if not next_page_token:
                break

        except HttpError as error:
            print(error)
    print("Total: ",len(video_ids),len(songs_ids))

    return video_ids,songs_ids
```

Comment: I recommend you to use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970181) to instantly create a new playlist in a quota-free manner.

Comment: @benjamin-loison Thank you that actually worked but I have another question if you don't mind when I'm extracting video id's from liked videos playlist I only got 991 results back but playlist have ~1900 videos ,is this any kind of limit from API or something?

Comment: Open another Stack Overflow for this purpose and explain there how you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in javascript is the below

```
/**
 * A recursive function that accepts a single track and makes repeated calls to the endpoint until the response is successful.
 * @param {String} accessToken The Google Auth Access Token required to make POST requests.
 * @param {Object} resourceId The Youtube track to POST into the Youtube playlist.
 * @param {String} playlistId The playlistId of what playlist to POST the tracks to.
 */
const postYoutubeTrack = async (accessToken, singleResourceId, playlistId) => {
  const request = await fetch(`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      snippet: {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        resourceId: {
          kind: singleResourceId.kind,
          videoId: singleResourceId.videoId,
        },
      },
    }),
  });

  if (request.ok) {
    const response = await request.json();
    return response;
  }

  postYoutubeTrack(accessToken, singleResourceId, playlistId);
};

export default postYoutubeTrack;
```