# How to create playlist youtube by cookie using request in python

Tags: python, youtube, playlist

As the title I mentioned how to create, and modify the playlist of a channel on youtube using cookies in python language.
Thank you very much for your positive feedback.

I tried using the API YouTube provides, but I want to find a way to use it with cookies.

Comment: [I answered this question concerned adding videos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970181/)), you should easily generalize it for creating playlists and removing videos from them.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @BenjaminLoison, 
Sorry if my question wasn't really clear.
In my question it is mentioned using request & cookies in python.
As of right now I know the API Youtube provides is usable, but I would like to learn more about using requests with cookies.
Best regards

Comment: My suggested approach uses cURL, without the YouTube API, so you should quite easily switch it to a Python requests implementation thanks to [this minimization algorithm](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/blob/f02e025bff6a38b40331611d97c03e82adc9701a/tools/minimizeCURL.py) for instance.