# Youtube Music API Python script mp3 files

Tags: python, mp3, youtube-data-api, playlist, eyed3

I have 5000+ mp3 files stored in my windows computer. I have writen a python script that comunicates with Youtube Music and almost succesfully creates a playlist with the songs (See script below).
I say almost succesfully because the gigantic issue is the YouTube Data API v3 daily quota (10000).

According to what I understand, after circa 60-70 songs, I hit the daily quota so the script stops including songs into the playlist. It seems that I am so close, but I have no idea how to solve this.
Here is the code:

```
import time
import os
import re
import eyed3
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
#import request
#from google.auth.transport.request


# API key from your Google Cloud Console project
api_key = "include_key_here"

# OAuth 2.0 flow
#flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
#    "client_secrets.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"]
#)

# Check if client_secrets.json exists in the same directory as the script
secrets_file_path = "client_secrets3.json"
if not os.path.exists(secrets_file_path):
    # If not, prompt the user to provide the path manually
    secrets_file_path = input("Enter the path to client_secrets.json: ")
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(secrets_file_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"])


credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

# Build the YouTube service
youtube = build("youtube", "v3", credentials=credentials)

# Songs to add to the playlist


def get_song_info(file_path):
    try:
        audiofile = eyed3.load(file_path)
        if audiofile is None:
            raise ValueError("Failed to load audio file")
        title = audiofile.tag.title
        artist = audiofile.tag.artist
        return {"title": title, "artist": artist}
    except (ValueError, Exception) as e:
        print(f"Error processing file {file_path}: {e}")
        return None

def process_folder(folder_path):
    songs = []
    not_identified_songs = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
            song_info = get_song_info(file_path)
            if song_info:
                songs.append(song_info)
            else:
                not_identified_songs.append(file_path)
    return songs, not_identified_songs

# Replace 'path_to_your_folder' with the actual path to your folder containing MP3 files
folder_path = 'G:\My Drive\desktop\Camilo\Todas mis músicas'
songs, not_identified_songs = process_folder(folder_path)

# Create a new playlist
playlist_response = youtube.playlists().insert(
    part="snippet,status",
    body={
        "snippet": {
            "title": "mp3 files",
            "description": "yeaah",
        },
        "status": {"privacyStatus": "PUBLIC"},  # Set privacy to public
    },
).execute()

playlist_id = playlist_response["id"]

failed_songs = []  # List to store songs that couldn't be added
for song in songs:
    try:
        search_response = youtube.search().list(
            part="snippet",
            q=f"{song['title']} {song['artist']}",
            type="VIDEO",
            maxResults=1,
        ).execute()

        # Check if there are items in the search response
        if "items" in search_response and search_response["items"]:
            video_id = search_response["items"][0]["id"]["videoId"]
            youtube.playlistItems().insert(
                part="snippet",
                body={
                    "snippet": {
                        "playlistId": playlist_id,
                        "resourceId": {"kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": video_id},
                    }
                },
            ).execute()
            print(f"Added {song['title']} by {song['artist']} to the playlist.")
        else:
            print(f"No video found for {song['title']} by {song['artist']}. Skipping.")
            failed_songs.append(song)
    except IndexError:
        print(f"Error: No videoId found for {song['title']} by {song['artist']}. Skipping.")
        failed_songs.append(song)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error adding {song['title']} by {song['artist']} to the playlist: {e}")
        failed_songs.append(song)


print("Playlist creation completed.")

# Print the list of songs that couldn't be added
if failed_songs:
    print("Songs that couldn't be added to the playlist:")
    for failed_song in failed_songs:
        print(f"- {failed_song['title']} by {failed_song['artist']}")
```

Comment: What's the question? How to get around the daily song limit...?

Comment: [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970181) may interest you.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure if I should just forget about it and create the playlist manually or if there is a way around the quota. It seems to me that there should be a way to literally "copy-paste" the name of the songs into a youtube music playlist.