# Add multiple videos to youtube-playlist in a single request via API (Python)

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm creating a tool to convert playlists between YouTube and Spotify, but the YouTube API has a problematic quota: each video costs 50 points (out of a daily total of 10,000), which is severely limiting my requests. Is there a way to add all the tracks in a list and add them all to the playlist in a single request?

```
import os
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from secret.credentials import Credentials
from controller import getter
from gui.colors import colored_text, ConsoleColors

# Define the scopes
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def extract_spotify_playlist_name(spotify_playlist_url):
    # Initialize Spotipy client
    client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(Credentials().get_id(), Credentials().get_secret())
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

    # Extract playlist ID from URL
    playlist_id = spotify_playlist_url.split('/')[-1]

    # Get playlist details
    playlist = sp.playlist(playlist_id)

    # Extract playlist name
    playlist_name = playlist['name']

    return playlist_name

def create_youtube_playlist(spotify_playlist_url, youtube_playlist_name):
    # Define the scopes
    SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"]

    # Load the credentials from json
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('ytb_credentials/client_secret.json'):
        creds = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'ytb_credentials/client_secret.json', SCOPES).run_local_server(port=0)

    # Construa o serviço YouTube API usando as credenciais
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Create YouTube playlist
    try:
        request = youtube.playlists().insert(
            part="snippet,status",
            body={
                "snippet": {
                    "title": youtube_playlist_name,
                    "description": f"This playlist was created from {youtube_playlist_name} using BridgeBeats. For more, acess github.com/lilrau.",
                    "tags": ["BridgeBeats"]
                },
                "status": {
                    "privacyStatus": "public"  # Change this to "private" if you want a private playlist
                }
            }
        )
        response = request.execute()
        playlist_id = response["id"]
        print(f"{colored_text('Playlist created successfully!', ConsoleColors.BACKGROUND_GREEN)} Playlist ID:", playlist_id)

        # Get tracks from Spotify playlist
        spotify_tracks = getter.get_spotify_tracks(spotify_playlist_url)

        # Add tracks to the YouTube playlist
        for track in spotify_tracks:
            try:
                # Search for the track on YouTube
                search_response = youtube.search().list(
                    q=f"{track['artist']} - {track['name']}",
                    part="id",
                    maxResults=1
                ).execute()

                # Add the first result to the playlist
                video_id = search_response["items"][0]["id"]["videoId"]
                youtube.playlistItems().insert(
                    part="snippet",
                    body={
                        "snippet": {
                            "playlistId": playlist_id,
                            "position": 0,
                            "resourceId": {
                                "kind": "youtube#video",
                                "videoId": video_id
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ).execute()

                print(f"Added {colored_text({track['artist']} - {track['name']}, ConsoleColors.GREEN)} to the playlist.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{colored_text(f"Error adding {track['artist']} - {track['name']} to the playlist:", ConsoleColors.RED)}", e)

    except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
        print(f"{colored_text('An error occurred while creating the playlist:', ConsoleColors.RED)}", e)
        return
```

I found in the forum a batch processing solution, but I don't know how to use it, so GPT gave me this solution (of course did not worked):

```
def create_youtube_playlist(spotify_playlist_url, youtube_playlist_name):
    # Load the credentials from json
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('ytb_credentials/client_secret.json'):
        creds = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'ytb_credentials/client_secret.json', SCOPES).run_local_server(port=0)

    # Build the YouTube API service
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Create YouTube playlist
    try:
        request = youtube.playlists().insert(
            part="snippet,status",
            body={
                "snippet": {
                    "title": youtube_playlist_name,
                    "description": f"This playlist was created from {youtube_playlist_name} using BridgeBeats. For more, acess github.com/lilrau.",
                    "tags": ["BridgeBeats"]
                },
                "status": {
                    "privacyStatus": "public"  # Change this to "private" if you want a private playlist
                }
            }
        )
        response = request.execute()
        playlist_id = response["id"]
        print(f"{colored_text('Playlist created successfully!', ConsoleColors.BACKGROUND_GREEN)} Playlist ID:", playlist_id)

        # Get tracks from Spotify playlist
        spotify_tracks = getter.get_spotify_tracks(spotify_playlist_url)

        # Prepare batch requests
        batch = youtube.new_batch_http_request(callback=batch_callback)
        
        # Add tracks to the YouTube playlist
        for track in spotify_tracks:
            try:
                # Search for the track on YouTube
                search_response = youtube.search().list(
                    q=f"{track['artist']} - {track['name']}",
                    part="id",
                    maxResults=1
                ).execute()

                # Add the first result to the playlist
                video_id = search_response["items"][0]["id"]["videoId"]
                batch.add(youtube.playlistItems().insert(
                    part="snippet",
                    body={
                        "snippet": {
                            "playlistId": playlist_id,
                            "position": 0,
                            "resourceId": {
                                "kind": "youtube#video",
                                "videoId": video_id
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ))
                
                print(f"Added {colored_text({track['artist']} - {track['name']}, ConsoleColors.GREEN)} to the batch.")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{colored_text(f"Error adding {track['artist']} - {track['name']} to the batch:", ConsoleColors.RED)}", e)

        # Execute batch requests
        batch.execute()

    except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
        print(f"{colored_text('An error occurred while creating the playlist:', ConsoleColors.RED)}", e)
        return

def batch_callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print(f"Request {request_id} failed: {exception}")
    else:
        print(f"Request {request_id} succeeded!")
```

Comment: [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970181) might interest you.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! It's sad to see this no-solution limitation , since the Spotify API has allowed me to create really large playlists without any issues so far. Apparently, YouTube is also quite problematic for increasing the quota, so the dream is probably over.